# How to take the first Input every 3 seconds in RxJs?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two Components that call a method in a service. Both make several calls but i only want to track one call and it should be the first one. In my example i get only one call but it is the last one, i want the first one.

Component 1:

Calling this method several times

```
this.myService.writexy('1')
```

Component 2:

Calling this method several times

```
this.myService.writexy('2')
```

MyService:

```
sub = new ReplaySubject(1);
  debounced = this.sub.pipe(
    debounce(() =>interval(3000))
  )

constructor() {
    this.debounced.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }

writexy(x) {
    this.sub.next(x);
  }
```

if the stream input is 1 2 the Output should be 1

Comment: Do you need to handle some kind of reset ? If not `take(1)` is your solution.

Comment: thx, no reset. take(1) does not work for me. I put it before or after the debounce or before the subscription, But no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [`throttle`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttle). It behaves similar to `debounce` but it emits the first value and suppresses further emits during the specified `interval`.

```js
const debounced = this.sub.pipe(
  throttle(val => interval(3000))
)
```

---

Or even shorter: `throttleTime`.

```
const debounced = this.sub.pipe(
  throttleTime(3000)
)
```